# Outlook Web Add-in : Ribbon button grayed out in Explorer view in Email

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am using ribbon button in outlook web addin to open a task pane. It works fine in outlook on web. But in outlook outlook desktop(2016) ribbon button are grayed out(disable) in explorer view of email.[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YG4L.jpg). But When open a email button is enable. I am using outlook 64 bit.

And this is manifest file i am using.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:ce44715c-8c4e-446b-879c-ea9ebe0f09c8-->
<OfficeApp 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" 
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>aeeb9a41-c591-4718-88e0-9ab3f4ec3eb9</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Davton</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Notify To Team" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Notify To Team"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/dvt-80.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/images/dvt-80.png" />

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.contoso.com" />
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/MessageRead.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile"/>
          <!--  Message Read  -->
          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/dvt-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/dvt-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/dvt-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/MessageRead.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Connector"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="Notify to Team"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Notify to Team"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Notify to Team"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane and select a dropdown channel to notify and notify"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile"/>
            <!-- Message Read -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                      <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                  <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/dvt-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/dvt-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300Images/dvt-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/MessageRead.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Connector"/>
          <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="Connector"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Notify to Team"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Notify to Team"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane and select a dropdown channel to notify and notify"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

can anyone help me to enable ribbon button in explorer view in outlook.

Comment: Sandun, which version (build number) of desktop outlook 2016 are you using? Can you share a screenshot of your ribbon when you switch to the "View" tab?

Comment: @OlegO I am using outlook version 1703 (build 7967.2139). http://imgur.com/a/djY8A this is the screen shot of view tab

Comment: No, I meant can you please switch to the View tab and take a screenshot of all ribbon buttons in that tab - sorry my request wasn't very clear...

Answer (score 3):

You have the issue with your manifest file. Change the following:

```
<bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300Images/dvt-80.png"/>
```

to:

```
<bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/dvt-80.png"/>
```

Comment: In addition, the reason it isn't causing an issue for OWA is it doesn't use the 80x80 image and your other URIs were correctly defined.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Thanks Mark, I was assuming the image is 80x80 as it called "dvt-80.png", but this is definitely something to verify as well.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov Thanks for the answer. I fixed the change but issue is (disable the ribbon button) still in outlook 2016

Comment: @SandunTharaka I didn't have your image, indeed. Instead I used my own images for manifest provided. In the manifest itself I changed the image name and fixed the line I posted as an answer. Manifest worked fine, image appeared enabled in Outlook 2016. Now what you can check: 1. Try to change image name in manifest and your resources (Images folder) to avoid cache option. 2. Check your images sizes and they are not corrupted. 3. Check you are running your application under "https://localhost:44300" and you able to navigate to image just with browser. Let me know.

Comment: @SlavaIvanovs Thanks, I done all the things you suggest. But disable ribbon button issue is still happen. I checked the same addin in outlook 32bit desktop. It works fine. But not work in 64bit outlook. Do you have suggestion for that.

Comment: @SandunTharaka Nothing to do with Outlook bitness. If you try to load your corrected manifest into yet another Outlook 64bit, just different computer/account it will work. You may verify it by removing your exchange account from Outlook (which right now has disabled icon) and add another account to the same Outlook, load manifest and you will see the icon enabled.